# Calling Angular Module Import After Cordova DeviceReady Event

Tags: angular, cordova

I need to call .forRoot(plugin) on an external library with a cordova plugin as the parameter after cordova's deviceReady event has fired. (so I know the plugin has loaded)

my main .ts file contains this:

```
let onDeviceReady = () => {
  console.log('deviceready');
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```

my app.module.ts file contains:

```
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    TcpCommunicationModule.forRoot(window.Socket)
  ],
  providers: [TcpCommunicationService],
```

Where TcpCommunicationService is a service of TcpCommunicationModule which is in an external library (which we control).

TcpCommunicationModule.ts contains this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [TcpCommunicationComponent],
  imports: [],
  exports: [TcpCommunicationComponent]
})
export class TcpCommunicationModule {
  public static forRoot(tcpSocket: any): ModuleWithProviders {
    console.log('forRoot called with object:');
    console.log(tcpSocket);
    return {
      ngModule: TcpCommunicationModule,
      providers: [
        TcpSocketFactoryService,
        {
          provide: 'tcpSocket',
          useValue: tcpSocket
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

and finally TcpSocketFactoryService.ts contains:

```
export class TcpSocketFactoryService {
  constructor(@Inject('tcpSocket') private tcpSocket) {}
}
```

my expectation is that bootstrap should be called after deviceready, and this bootstrap process should call `TcpCommunicationModule.forRoot(window.Socket)` from the AppModule's import section. However my actual console output shows .forRoot() being called before the bootstrap, ie:

```
'forRoot called with object:'
undefined
'deviceready'
'Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.'
```

How can I get .forRoot() to be called as part of the bootstrap process (ie, after device ready)? If I move it's call to a button click or the like it's too late and I get a staticInjector error message that 'tcpSocket' is not present.

Answer (score 0):

This was abandoned. The Cordova plugins clobber themselves as available in the global scope. Less control over typing but external library can access them, so functionality achieved.